# Change the foreground color of a ListView item only in one column

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a List of objects and a ListView where I display this list. Such an object has some properties, they are bound to the columns of the ListView.

```
<ListView x:Name="_fileNameList" FontSize="12" SourceUpdated="_fileNameList_SourceUpdated" TargetUpdated="_fileNameList_TargetUpdated">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="FileNameAttributes" >
            <GridViewColumn  Header="File Name"   Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fileName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Size" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding size}"/>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Date" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding date}"/>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Time" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}"/>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="New Name" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding newFileName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This part is working fine.

Now I want to change the Foreground color of the `newFileName` column in a single row, but only if it is equal to the 'fileName' in the same row.

Can I do this in XAML or do I have to go to the code behind file?

I would like it best if I could handle it in XAML, because I think its a pure design issue, but I have no idea, where to start or where to put this, (can I do String comparisons in XAML?)

So I tried to handle this in the code behind file. I thought there must be an event that is raised when the ListView has changed, I tried the `SourceUpdated` event, but it is not entered when I change the content of my list.
The next problem would be, how to access those ListView items ...

Can anyone give me an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: I've never done this myself, but you can try create a custom converter (like those for visibility) and bind the Foreground property to this converter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using MultiBinding and MultiConverter.
You will need to write a MultiConverter which takes fileName and newFileName and returns true if they are equal

```
<ListView x:Name="_fileNameList" FontSize="12" SourceUpdated="_fileNameList_SourceUpdated" TargetUpdated="_fileNameList_TargetUpdated">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="FileNameAttributes" >
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="File Name"   Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fileName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Size" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding size}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Date" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding date}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Time" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="New Name" Width="300">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding newFileName}">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                 <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                                     <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                                                             <Binding Path="newFileName"></Binding>
                                                             <Binding Path="fileName"></Binding>
                                                         </MultiBinding>
                                                     </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

The code for EqualityConverter is as below :

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values[0].ToString().Equals(values[1].ToString()))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I created the MultiConverter class in the code behind file, but when I try to reference it in the resource section, I get an error "type was not found", how do I need to reference it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it to work (had the MultiConverter class in the wrong place). Works wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

if you wanna change the style of any wpf element you should use the Style. if you want it happen on some conditions you should use Style.Triggers. if your conditions belong to binding information you should use DataTrigger. And if the XAML datatrigger can not handle your condition add a converter.

so i would suggest you to take a datatrigger in your GridViewColum.Style and a multiconverter with 2 parameters filename and newfilename. return true if it the same otherwise false.

something like that:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
  <DataTrigger.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyFileNameCheckConverter}">
        <Binding Path="fileName"/>
        <Binding Path="newFileName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </DataTrigger.Binding>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
 </DataTrigger>
```

converter

```
public class FileNameCheckConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var filename = (string)values[0];
        var newfilename = (string)values[1];

        return filename==newfilename;
    }

    ...
}
```

ps: dont forget to set the "normal" foreground in your style too! otherwise the trigger stuff will not work.

pps: code is handwritten

Comment: Addition: Change CellTemplate of the particular column as GridViewColumn is not a framework element.

Comment: Thanks (+1) you gave me also important hints to get it to work.