# WPF:change background color of listview item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, vb.net-2010

how to change the foreground(even Background will do) of item in listview.
i have a program which opens excel and check for broken links in the given sheet.
i want to display the user the list of given links and whcih ever is broken. i want to change foreground to RED.
i have bound the values to observablecollection. the collection is just collection of strings(WEB LINKS) and is working fine

should i do multi binding like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324502/change-the-foreground-color-of-a-listview-item-only-in-one-column)

**EDIT:-**
 have got one more problem on this. after creating the property and making all the changes. the WPF form is not getting updated with the values. i.e. the list box is not getting filled. neither the coloring is happening( not sure it is happening also. as i cant see them).

here is my code. please excuse my coding i am new to WPF

```
<Window x:Class="URLValide.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:URL_Validater.URLValide"
Title="URL Validator" Height="269" Width="525" FontSize="13"
ResizeMode="NoResize">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="HighLight" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Honeydew"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="UltraBlack"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="40" Color="Beige" Direction="50" Opacity="0.5"/>                                
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="WinHeader"  Height="30" Background="BurlyWood" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" FontStretch="Medium" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">URL Validator</Label>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Beige">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" MaxHeight="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Current URL:"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding strCrnUrl}"  Width="370"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"  Text="10 of 100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="154">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="300" Width="19*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="55" MinHeight="10" Height="35*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="165*"  MinHeight="10"  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Name="LbleRight" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,2" FontSize="13" Content="List Of URL's" Height="30" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Background="Azure" ItemsSource="{Binding strPdfLst}" IsEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,1"></ListView>            
    </Grid>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60*" />                
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
        <Label BorderBrush="Black" Name="lblFleSel" BorderThickness="1" Height="27" Margin="2,2,0,30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="349">Select File To which Contains the list of URL's:</Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtbxFleNme" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2,34,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HighLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="272"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="btnFleSlec" Width="69" Height="27" Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="276,32,4,0"></Button>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="118" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" Name="OptionGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="117" Margin="3,1,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="350">
                    <!--<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162" Height="118">                        
                    </StackPanel>-->
                    <Grid Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="335">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkboxHas" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Has Column Headers</CheckBox>
                        <Label Name="lblDesc" Height="auto" Margin="0,0,204,0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">Description Column:</Label>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Name="cmboxDescol"  Margin="131,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HighLight}"></ComboBox>
                        <Label Name="lblUrlCol" Height="auto" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,204,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">URL's Column:</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cmboxUrlCol" Grid.Row="2" Margin="131,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HighLight}"></ComboBox>
                        <Label Name="lblResCol" Height="auto" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,196,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Result Column:</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cmboxResCol" Grid.Row="3" Margin="131,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HighLight}"></ComboBox>
                        <Button Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Validate URL links" Name="btnValidate"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>                    
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

i am not sure if i should be posting full code. but here is my class
the button click will start the program.

My class code:-

```
    Imports Microsoft
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Namespace URLValide

    Public Class clsUrlCheck
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

        Public Event propertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        Public exclApplic As New Excel.Application
        Public exclWkbOpe As Excel.Workbook
        Public exclWksAct As Excel.Worksheet
        Public exclRngUrl As Excel.Range
        Public exclRngDes As Excel.Range
        Public exclRngOut As Excel.Range
        Public intMaxRow As Long
        Public intCrtRow As Long
        Private _strTotlOf As String
        Private _strCrnUrl As String
        Private _ColorIndx As String
        Private _strPdfLst As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Private _strhdrPdf As ObservableCollection(Of String)

#Region "Region of poperties"
        Public Property strTotlOf() As String
            Get
                Return _strTotlOf
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _strTotlOf = value
                Me.OnPropertyChanged("strTotlOf")
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property strCrnUrl() As String
            Get
                Return _strCrnUrl
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _strCrnUrl = value
                Me.OnPropertyChanged("strCrnUrl")
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property strPdfLst As ObservableCollection(Of String)
            Get
                Return _strPdfLst
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
                _strPdfLst = value
                Me.OnPropertyChanged("strPdfLst")
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property strhdrPdf As ObservableCollection(Of String)
            Get
                Return _strhdrPdf
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
                _strhdrPdf = value
                Me.OnPropertyChanged("strhdrPdf")
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property ColorIndx As String
            Get
                Return _ColorIndx
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ColorIndx = value
                Me.OnPropertyChanged("ColorIndx")
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
            RaiseEvent propertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End Sub
#End Region

#Region "function of Validating the URL's"
        Public Function UrlCheck(ByVal strUrlReq As String)

            Try

                Dim WebReq As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrlReq)
                WebReq.Method = "Head"
                WebReq.Timeout = 5000
                Using Response = WebReq.GetResponse()
                    Return True
                End Using

            Catch ex As Exception
                ColorIndx = "True"
                Return False

            End Try

        End Function
#End Region

#Region "Start Function"
        Sub suStart()
            Dim blnValid As Boolean


            'strPdfLst.Clear()
            'strPdfLst = makeList(exclRngUrl.Column, False)
            If exclRngDes.Value = "Make Desc" Then
                strPdfLst = makeList(exclRngUrl.Column, True)
                exclRngDes.Delete()
            Else
                strPdfLst = makeList(exclRngUrl.Column, False)
            End If

            For Each exclRngEch As Excel.Range In exclRngUrl
                strCrnUrl = exclRngEch.Text
                strTotlOf = exclRngEch.Row & "OF" & intMaxRow
                blnValid = UrlCheck(exclRngEch.Value.ToString)
                If blnValid Then
                    exclWksAct.Cells(exclRngEch.Row, exclRngOut.Column).value = "Web Page Present"
                Else
                    exclWksAct.Cells(exclRngEch.Row, exclRngOut.Column).value = "Web Page Error"

                End If

            Next


        End Sub

        Function makeList(ByVal intColNum As Long, ByVal blnMkeStr As Boolean) As ObservableCollection(Of String)

            Dim ObsColTem As ObservableCollection(Of String) = New ObservableCollection(Of String)

            If Not blnMkeStr Then
                For intLopCnt As Int32 = intCrtRow To intMaxRow
                    ObsColTem.Add(exclWksAct.Cells(intLopCnt, intColNum).Text)
                Next
            Else
                For intLopCnt As Int32 = intCrtRow To intMaxRow
                    Dim strDesc As String = Mid(exclWksAct.Cells(intLopCnt, intColNum).Text, InStrRev(exclWksAct.Cells(intLopCnt, intColNum).Text, "/", , CompareMethod.Text) + 1)
                    ObsColTem.Add(strDesc)
                Next
            End If
            Return ObsColTem
        End Function
#End Region

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Is the "strPdfLst" an ObservableCollection or  just a List<string> ?

Comment: it is ObservableCollection

Comment: Ok and do you have set the DataContext to the Object that contains the "strPdfLst"?

Comment: yes. during the Initialize i have done it

Comment: Hi sine. thank you very much. i am also making changes to few textboxes. it is working. but the form is getting hanged. i cant move it or anything. till it completes. it shows like blank screen. after it is completed. it shows the recent changed texts. i used snoop and the bindings are correct.not sure why it is hanging.

Comment: sorry I don´t know much about VB, but in C# you could try to do your work in a backgroundworker, don´t forget to use Dispatcher when accessing UI-Elements from a Thread! And If my answer solved your problem with setting back/foreground please accept it as answer! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from working code

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RowSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro"  />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a converter which takes the link as parameter and send the background/foreground color, the converters checks the link and sends the correct code accordingly,bind the color code to the itemtemplate background/foreground property.

Answer (score 0):

First create a Broken-Property which you can bind to and then just create a Style for ListViewItems with a DataTrigger on the Broken-Property!

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
<Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Broken}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Have not tested this code but it should work!

Comment: I have got one more problem on this. after creating the property and making all the changes. the WPF form is not getting updated with the values. i.e. the list box is not getting filled. neither the coloring is happening( not sure it is happening also. as i cant see them).

Comment: can you please update your question and share more code not only the xaml, I need to see your code-behind to say more!